# Difference between authorization and sale transactions method in paypal

Tags: php, paypal, opencart

I just need to understand the main difference between authorization and sale transaction types in PayPal.

Does the sale provides capture facility along with it?

Which one will be better for my store?

I am using OpenCart for my store.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does the sale provides capture facility along with it?

Yes, in paypal autherization means bank verified the account like has credit, verify adress and user or other information about cardOwner then just block the amount but not charge it yet until "capture" is done.

In sale you don't have to capture the amount you already make the final sale and you already charged. Please check below links for more details:

[auth-only-vs-final-sale-for-PayPal](http://www.zen-cart.com/showthread.php?124272-auth-only-vs-final-sale-for-PayPal)

[paypal-online-payment-action-sale-authorization.html](http://blog.ecommercesoftwaresolutionsonline.com/archives/366/paypal-online-payment-action-sale-authorization.html)

[What is the difference between Authorization, Capture, and Sale?](https://support.cybersource.com/cybskb/index?page=content&id=C35&actp=LIST)

> Which one will be better for my store?

After check this you should be decide which one is suitable for you, if you need a confirmation after you post the product then you can select auth+capture or if you want to charge user at one step you should select sale.

Answer (score 1):

Today it is Authorization, Order and Sale that you can choose from. The differences are very well explained here:

https://www.paypal-knowledge.com/infocenter/index?page=content&widgetview=true&id=FAQ1501

In short authorization is a real credit card authorization valid only 72 hours, capture is a prenoted purchase without a real credit card authorization (valid for 29 days). Sale is the full process of authorizing and capturing in one command.

Comment: Please do not share links which can be later movied or deleted. Just simply copy-paste relevant info, because in this case the link is dead...

Comment: Of course the link is dead. Their documentation and site is utterly useless.